# How can I unset Google Translator as default translator

Tags: default-applications, google-translate

I am having a problem.
If I select a part of a web pages in my browser, I could tap on translate and then choose between various translators (including DeepL).
I accidentally set Google Translator as default and now there aren't any other translators. The only thing I can do now is choosing Google Translator.
I would like to undo my false selection of Google Translator as default.
How is this possible?

Comment: You don't provide the specific device or operating system, so this can be only in generalized fashion. Check settings for Apps>Default Apps (or similar). Google Translate should be in the list of apps there, and see if it can have its default permission removed that way.

Comment: I use a Samsung Galaxy A72 with Android 13. Unfortunately there isn't any option to specify a default translator application via Apps>Default App.

Comment: "I accidentally set Google Translator as default and now there aren't any other translators." Did you set it up as the default for the browser or for the phone?

Comment: There were to options within the interface to choose the translator app that should be used. 1st Use once 2nd Use always I accidentally chose the 2nd one. It looks like that I have set the default translator application for the whole phone, not just for the browser. Especially the behaviour of the translator function is the same in different applications than the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for the inconvenience caused by my question.

I could set DeepL as default translator via the application of Twitter.
After having set DeepL as default translator application I reset the application of Mozilla Firefox via the application settings. Still Google Translator was used as translator when choosing translate in the context menu of a selected text in the application of Mozilla Firefox.
It turned out that I didn't choose Google Translator as default translator. Using Google Translator as default translator seems to be the application of Mozilla Firefox' default behaviour.